# Hi everyone I have a json file that I want to read A sample code from the file I have

Tags: php, json

I have a json file that I want to read A sample code from the file I have

```
        [
 {
   "id": "bd91c44716e562f025eb70f7df083f2e",
   "title": "ATP Australian Open",
   "commence_time": "2022-01-18T03:24:34Z",
   "bookmakers": [
     {
       "key": "corn",
       "title": "corn",
       "last_update": "2022-01-18T06:56:38Z",
       "markets": [
         {
           "key": "spreads",
           "outcomes": [
             {
               "name": "two",
               "number": 56
             },
             {
               "name": "one",
               "point": -67
             }
           ]
         }
       ]
     }
   ]
 },
 {
   "id": "5d9a5870d42fa199d0ab330b4c3767ce",
   "title": "Open",
   "commence_time": "2022-01-18T04:07:20Z",
   "bookmakers": [
```

As you can see, there are four parameters with similar names Now how do I get all four? I'm a novice, please help me

Comment: Please post a complete example. What you've posted isn't a valid json structure for multiple reasons.

Comment: Yes, I will definitely put it now

Comment: Also include what you're actually trying to do. Read it how? For what? Do what with the data? There are _plenty_ of guides about reading JSON in PHP so what have you tried so far? What was the expected result and what currently happens with your attempt?

Comment: Still not a complete example. That JSON is cut off. You also need to answer my other questions/comments (adding it to your question as well), or we won't even know what you're trying to do or where you're stuck.